# equation $x+y=z$ in $\{1,\dots,n\}$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Let $k,n$ be two positive integers such that $n\ge k>\frac{n+1}{2}$.

Prove that every $k$-element subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ contains numbers $x,y,z$ satisfying $x+y=z$.

---

Problem found in olympiad-training materials. I spent much time on it, but without any idea.

Comment: Take the smallest number $a$ in the $k$ set and subtract it from the others. Assuming $x+y=z$ never holds in the $k$ set, the map $x\mapsto x-a$ gives you a bijection from the $k$ set excluding  $a$ to the complement of the $k$ set (posibly including $a$). Therefore the should be as many elements inside as outside. But $k>\frac{n+1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the smallest number $a$ in the $k$ set and subtract it from the others. Assuming $x+y=z$ never holds in the $k$ set, the map $x\mapsto x-a$ gives you a bijection from the $k$ set excluding  $a$ to the complement of the $k$ set (posibly including $a$). Therefore the should be as many elements inside as outside. But $k>\frac{n+1}{2}$.

Comment: Very elegant solution!